# puppet dashboard fails to start

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, puppet, ruby, ruby-rack

So here's the situation. I'm running Puppet on CentOS 5.7 64-bit, and on the puppet master I also have puppet-dashboard, however when I try to start it, I see the following:

```
[root@puptest-master puppet-dashboard]# script/server -e production
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rack (~> 1.1.0) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.1, actionpack-3.1.1, activemodel-3.1.1, activerecord-3.1.1, activeresource-3.1.1, activesupport-3.1.1, arel-2.2.1, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.21, daemon_controller-0.2.6, erubis-2.7.0, fastthread-1.0.7, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, json-1.6.1, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.16, multi_json-1.0.3, passenger-3.0.9, polyglot-0.3.2, rack-1.3.5, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.1.1, railties-3.1.1, rake-0.9.2, rdoc-3.11, sprockets-2.0.3, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.30] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /opt/puppet-dashboard/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb:34
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/puppet-dashboard/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /opt/puppet-dashboard/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /opt/puppet-dashboard/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /opt/puppet-dashboard/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:2
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Now what's interesting, is that bit about rack. I checked the rack version and it seems to be fine:

```
[root@puptest-master puppet-dashboard]# rackup --version
Rack 1.1 (Release: 1.3)
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`rack-1.3.5` is the version number on the current copy, but `rack (~> 1.1.0)` is the version constraint that's been specified - they call this the "[Pessimistic Version Constraint](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74)", and it's preventing anything newer than `1.1.x` from fulfilling this dependency.

You'll need an older version of rack, or, maybe this "1.1 (Release: 1.3)" will work just fine - you could just try changing the version spec to `>=` instead of `~>`, and see if it'll load.